# R - Assigning multiple values based on one vector (if x = 1, set these variables = -99)

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, apply

I'm having a little bit of a problem with attempting to set a multitude of variables to a specific value (-99) based on the value of another variable. This frequently comes up in my survey work.

```
v1 <- c("Blue","Blue","Red","Red","Blue")
v2 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
v3 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
v4 <- c(1,1,1,2,2)
v5 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

x = data.frame (v1,v2,v3,v4,v5)
```

Take this example dataframe for instance. Usually, to accomplish setting v2 thorugh v5 to -99, if v1 was "Blue", I would end up doing several statements like this ...

```
x$v2[x$v1 == "Blue"] <- -99
x$v3[x$v1 == "Blue"] <- -99
```

Obviously this approach has a multitude of drawbacks, especially since some of my data sets can be large. In another program, I would use a statement like this ...

```
(for i in v2:v5, 
if v1 = Blue, set i = -99)
```

I've been attempting to use a for-loop in R without too much avail a few my attempts revolve around statements, such as this..

```
for(i in x$v2:v5){
i[x$v1 == "Blue"] <- -99 
}
```

If anyone could give me a hand with what i'm attempting to do here, I would greatly appreciate it. I'm thinking that I may be overthinking it, and able to do something like this with the apply family of functions.

Output, should look like this..

```
v1 <- c("Blue","Blue","Red","Red","Blue")
v2 <- c(-99,-99,3,4,-99)
v3 <- c(-99,-99,3,4,-99)
v4 <- c(-99,-99,1,2,-99)
v5 <- c(-99,-99,3,4,-99)
x = data.frame (v1,v2,v3,v4,v5)
```

Thanks Again Everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the logical index `x$v1 == "Blue"` to subset the rows and `-1` to remove the first column as it is the non-numeric column, and assign those to `-99`.

```
x[x$v1 == "Blue", -1] <- -99
x
#    v1  v2  v3  v4  v5
#1 Blue -99 -99 -99 -99
#2 Blue -99 -99 -99 -99
#3  Red   3   3   1   3
#4  Red   4   4   2   4
#5 Blue -99 -99 -99 -99
```

---

An efficient approach would be `set` from `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(x)`), loop through columns 2 to the last column, and `set` the 'value' to each column based on the logical index in 'i'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)
for(j in 2:ncol(x)){
   set(x, i = which(x$v1 =="Blue"), j = j, value = -99)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun ! These both work! I've looked through the extract help file and can't find any reference to the " -1]" portion of your answer. Could you expand a little more upon that? / What is the -1 doing?

Comment: @Madcap Read `help("[")`. You could use `2:5` instead.

Comment: @Madcap And I hope you know that R offers actual `NA` values.